# validate Well-formed xml on iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, validation

I'm using TBXML which doesn't have validation.
so if for some reason my servers sends a invalid formed xml to my TBXML parser it crashes.

is it possible to check the xml if its well formed before parsing it with my TBXML parser?

Answer (score 0):

```
 TBXML * tbxml = [[TBXML alloc] initWithURL:XmlUrl];
 if (tbxml) 
  {
  TBXMLElement * root = tbxml.rootXMLElement; 
  if (root) 
    { 
    // some data
}
}
```

use this method where you use TBXML ...
when xml is Correct then console is enter in if condition of tbxml

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running it through NSXMLParser? That has a parserError property you can check to see if there were any validation errors before you pass it to TBXML.